# how to create new column and store value using equation

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

The column `size` has multiple values. Tor `x` in column `size`, `y` (predicted value) is calculated. How do  display existing column `size` and predicted value `y`?

```
for x in df['size']:
    y=(0.7118*x)+1.1691
```

Comment: I geuss you are working with dataframes. You can use `.apply()` method: `f["predicted"] = f["size"].apply(lambda x: 0.7118*x+1.1691)`. This will apply your equation to each item in the series and assign it to a new column "predicted"

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df['y'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x: 0.7118*x + 1.1691)
```

Comment: You should try to avoid `.apply` if possible, because it's not very efficient, in particular here, were more natural approaches are available.

Comment: Indeed, but this give you an idea on what you can do with custom function that have nothing to do with basic algebra. Also performance was never mentioned.

Comment: Sure, performance wasn't mentioned, but should always be a concern, shouldn't it? (One of the most common Pandas anti-patterns is the overuse of `.apply` in places were idiomatic Pandas-methods would do the job.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```py
df["Y"] = 0.7118 * df["size"] + 1.1691
```

or

```py
df["Y"] = df["size"].mul(0.7118).add(1.1691)
```